How do I change the colour of my Portal gun in Portal 2?
I saw a video of someone playing Portal 2 and their Portal gun was purple. So somehow he changed the colour of it:

How do you change the colour of your Portal gun?

It appears to be obtained by modding, as discussed on Stream Community.
If interested, I found this tutorial.
